# No module named 'google.appengine' from within Cloud Shell

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I'm testing Google App Engine and trying to run a simple function to upload files to either the Blobstore or Cloud Storage. I'm typing the Python code directly in the Cloud Shell of my instance. The code is failing when I call:

`from google.appengine.ext import blobstore`

I get the error code:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import users
ImportError: No module named 'google.appengine'`

Even though the documentation says that: [You can use Google Cloud Shell, which comes with git and Cloud SDK already installed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart), I've tried installing a bunch of libraries:

`gcloud components install app-engine-python`

`pip install google-cloud-datastore`

`pip install google-cloud-storage`

`pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

I'm still getting the same error. How can I get the appengine library to work? Alternatively, is this the wrong method for creating an app that allows the user to upload files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dustin Ingram

I found the answer in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage).

The current "correct" way of uploading to Cloud Storage is to use `google.cloud.storage`. The tutorial I linked above explains how to implement it.

The impression I have, however, is that this uses twice the bandwidth as the solution via `google.appengine`. Originally, the front-end would receive an upload url and send the file directly to the Blobstore (or to Cloud Storage). Now the application uploads to the back-end which, in turn, uploads to Cloud Storage.

I'm not too worried, as I will not be dealing with excessively large files, but it seems strange that the ability to upload directly has been discontinued.

In any case, my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5):

The `google.appengine` module is baked into the first-generation Python (2.7) runtime. It's not available to install via `pip`, in the second-generation (3.7) runtime, or in Cloud Shell.

The only way to use it is by writing and deploying a first-generation App Engine app.

Comment: That explains my difficulty in finding an answer... What is the current best method for receiving file uploads from an application?